# Linking button to jQuery through service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

I have a small problem that should be very easy to overcome. For some reason I cant work this out. So the problem is I cannot get a button to link to some jquery. My set-up is as follows (showing the relevant code):

### **Default.aspx**

**jQuery:**

```
function getContent() {
    var data = {
        numberID: 1
    };

    $.jsonAspNet("ContentService.asmx", "GetContent", data,

    function (result) {
        $('#content').html(result);
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    getContent();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

### **ContentService.vb**

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetContent(number As Integer) As String
        Dim sb = New StringBuilder

        sb.AppendLine("<table>")
        sb.AppendLine("<tr>")
        sb.AppendLine("<td class='ui-widget-header ui-corner-all'>Number</td>")
        sb.AppendLine("</tr>")
        sb.AppendLine("<tr>")
        sb.AppendLine("<td>" & number & "</td>")
        sb.AppendLine("<td><a href='#' id='test' class='fg-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all'><img src='" & Context.Request.ApplicationPath & "/images/spacer.gif' class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil' /></a></td>")
        sb.AppendLine("</tr>")        
        sb.AppendLine("</table>")

        Return sb.ToString
    End Function
```

So that's the basics of what I have everything works but I'm not sure how to get the  a button (`id='test'`) to get linked to some jQuery. I want it to be pressed and bring up a popup.

I have tried to put the jQuery on `default.aspx` but this doesn't seem to work unless the button is place in the HTML on that page.

```
$('#test').unbind('click').click(function () {
    alert('Working');
});
```

I'm sure this is easy to do, but I have been trying for a while and cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: So you just want an alert when you click on the a href with the ID test?

Comment: @NickN. Pretty much, well I will do other things but I just cant get it to link. The alerts just there to show it works.

Comment: Yeah I got that, was just asking if you ment the a, with the term button. Try my answer

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that your document ready is not closed correctly? I'll change it in your question.

Comment: And another thing, since your using the jQuery tag in your document ready, shouldn't you replace all $ tags with jQuery. What does the Chrome console say? (CTRL-SHIFT-J)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Solved**

It was a very small thing that caused this. The code to fix this problem is as follows:

```js
$('#test').unbind('click').click(test);
```

This needed to go inside the function with the `json` so:

```js
function getContent() {
    var data = {
        numberID: 1
    };

    $.jsonAspNet("ContentService.asmx", "GetContent", data,

    function (result) {
        $('#content').html(result);
        $('#test').unbind('click').click(test);
    });
}
```

Thank you to everyone that has tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

As you load the content via ajax, you have to bind to `$('#content')`. Like this:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#content').on('click', '#test', function () {
        e.preventDefault(); // if a default action is not needed needed
        alert('Working');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem that you're trying to bind to the element that ISN'T in existance yet?

are you calling the `$('#test').unbind('click').click(function () {
    alert('Working');
});` BEFORE the service has returned?

```js
$('#test').on('click', function () {
      alert('Working');
});
```

This will bind the event to the '#test' element once it has been inserted in to the DOM.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, Im sure this should work but again its not reaching the jQuery.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle that I can have a look at?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is about not preventing the default behaviour of the A href tag. Now it will probably link to '#' instead of firing the onclick event.

```js
$('#test').on('click', function (e) {
    alert('Working');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You could try to wrap this in a document ready, or eventually use the `.on` binder from jQuery, since it's dynamic content.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I'm sure this should work but again its not reaching the jQuery. If I look at the source on a browser it shows the code correct. Like I said if the code is on the same page it will work but not when its coming from `content.vb`.